# $\{f :f\text{ is continuous and }f(0)=f(1)\}$ is Banach

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Show that 
the subspace 
$S=\{f : f\text{ is continuous and }f(0)=f(1)\} $ equipped with the infinity norm is Banach.

(It's enough to show that it's closed)

#### My try to solve it

Take $f_n$  sequence of functions such that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the norm
Then$ |f_n(x)-f(x)| \rightarrow 0 $   for all $ x$

Letting $x=0$

$|f_n(0)-f(0)| \rightarrow0$

$|f_n(1)-f(0)| \rightarrow0$

But I think this will not lead me to the answer.

Can we find a finite set of bases that spans this set so we can say it's finite dimensional?

Comment: You certainly can't say the set is finite-dimensional - for any $n$ you can have $f()$ take on arbitrary values at $i\cdot 2^{-n}$ for $1\leq i\leq 2^n-1$ and (continuously) linearly interpolate between them, so the dimension is at least $2^n-1$. Since $n$ was arbitrary...

Comment: No, that will lead to the answer: $f(0)= \lim f_n(0) = \lim 0 = 0.$

Comment: It is sufficient to show the complement is open. A ball in our space is {g| max{|(f-g)(x)|} is less than epsilon}. Assume f(0) is not f(1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said it's enough to show it's closed; that's true. Note now that $f(0)=f(1)$ is equivalent to $f(0)-f(1)=0$. So your set is the preimage of $\{ 0 \}$ under $G(f)=f(0)-f(1)$. Can you conclude?

Comment: Since it's continuous linear operator so kerlG is closed ?

Comment: @user283366 The use of linearity is a bit overkill, but yeah.

Answer (score 2):

@Ian's answer already shows a nice way to finish your proof. Another approach to see $S$ is a Banach space is to realize that **$S$ is isometric to $C(T)$**, where $C(T)$ denotes the Banach space of continuous functions on the torus $T:=\mathbb{R}\big/\mathbb{Z}$. To prove it just define $\varphi:S\to C(T)$ by
$$
\varphi(f):=\tilde{f},\hspace{.5cm}\tilde{f}(\bar{x}):=f(\{x\}),
$$
where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.
The condition $f(0)=f(1)$ in the definition of $S$ guarantees that this is well-defined. As $\varphi$ is trivially a isometry we have that $S$ is isometric to $C(T)$, and therefore a Banach space.